# View queued transactions with go-ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to see all transactions, that were queued at a past block. Lets say in block 2000000 with geth. Is there a way to do that?
Is there a way to see current queued transactions?

Comment: Hi there. Just to clarify: you mean transactions that were _pending_ at the time a particular block was being mined? And not the transactions that were actually _included_ in the block?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am trying to find out how long it takes for transactions on average to go from pending to validated.

Comment: Aha. Good question. +1

Comment: You can access currently pending txs in your node with txpool, but this are only the txs that have reached your node. I think it is very difficult to know all the pending txs at any point in the blockchain history.